# Extract words from sentence into array based on a string

Tags: php, templates, text, logic, extract

I am looking for the most efficient solution that will enable me build a string template for extracting the words & phrases from a sentence that uses the template structure.

Let's say that I have a `string` as follows:

```
$template = '%% is %% because %%.';
```

Now, let's say that I have an array of strings:

```
$strings = [
    'Cheese is the best thing because it is great on chips.',
    'My brother is my best friend because he\'s always been there.', 
    'Listen! StackOverflow is how I am still employed because I am not afraid to ask for help.',
    'Derp... Why is it that I can\'t do this easily? Maybe it is because I need more practice.'
];
```

I need logic that can extract the text in position of where the `%%` wildcards are in the `$template` so that the `$strings` array can be used to produce the following:

```
$template = '%% is %% because %%.';
$result = [
    ['Cheese','the best thing','it is great on chips.'],
    ['My brother','my best friend','he\'s always been there.'], 
    ['Listen! StackOverflow','how I am still employed','I am not afraid to ask for help.'],
    ['Derp... Why', 'it that I can\'t do this easily? Maybe it is','I need more practice.']
];
```

**Note**: Using 'explode' with the physical words/letters is not a great option because some words may have multiple occurrences and we only want to target the first occurrence in such an event.

Comment: Why wouldn't "it is great on chips." also be split?

Comment: @l'L'l

Because 'it **is** great on chips' is the second occurence. For it to split on the second occurrence, the template must be directive of that. ie: "%% is %% because %% is %%" This is why looping/using explode is not viable and I didn't even try using that kind of logic. Regex seems to be the best route to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression as the template:

```
$template = '(.+?) is (.+?) because (.+?)';

foreach($strings as $string) {
    preg_match("/$template/", $string, $matches);
    $result[] = [$matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]];
    //or
    //$result[] = array_slice($matches, 1);
}
```

You want to add some error checking in case there are no matches, or only 1 or 2 etc.

If for some reason you need that specific template nomenclature then:

```
$template = '%% is %% because %%.';
$template = str_replace('%%', '(.+?)', $template);
```

Comment: Wonderful. This works is actually pretty fast. Thanks for the quick help @AbraCadaver.